# Error when checking input: expected input_39 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 50, 780)

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, lstm, word-embedding

I am trying to put a word embedding on my Encoder-Decoder, but there seems to be some dimension issue.

```
encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
x = Embedding(nEncoderToken, embedding_dim, weights=[encoder_embedding_matrix])(encoder_inputs)
x, state_h, state_c = LSTM(embedding_dim, return_state=True)(x)
encoder_states = [state_h, state_c]

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,))
y = Embedding(nDecoderToken, embedding_dim, weights=[decoder_embedding_matrix], input_length=max_len)(decoder_inputs)
y = LSTM(embedding_dim, return_sequences=True)(decoder, initial_state=encoder_states)
decoder_outputs = Dense(nDecoderToken, activation='softmax')(x)

model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

Up till here, there are no errors. And the model summary is

```
Model: "model_17"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_39 (InputLayer)           (None, None)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input_40 (InputLayer)           (None, None)         0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_41 (Embedding)        (None, None, 300)    234000      input_39[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
embedding_42 (Embedding)        (None, 50, 300)      239100      input_40[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_33 (LSTM)                  [(None, 300), (None, 721200      embedding_41[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_34 (LSTM)                  (None, 50, 300)      721200      embedding_42[0][0]               
                                                                 lstm_33[0][1]                    
                                                                 lstm_33[0][2]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_17 (Dense)                (None, 50, 797)      239897      lstm_34[0][0]                    
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,155,397
Trainable params: 2,155,397
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

However when I try to fit the model,

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit([trainInputEncoded, trainInputDecoded], trainTargetDecoded, epochs=100)
```

I get **Error when checking input: expected input_39 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (100, 50, 780)**

I tried tweaking around things the whole day but got nowhere.  The only way I could do it is if I put Input(shape=(None, nEncoderToken)) and remove the Embedding Layer altogether.

Comment: Do not remove the Embedding layer, use Input(shape=(None, nEncoderToken)), then what error are you getting?

Comment: `Input 39 is incompatible with layer lstm_33: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

Comment: This is because you are giving batch_size=None in the shape argument. So either change it as Input(shape=(,)) or Input(batch_shape=(None,))

Comment: `Input(shape=(,))` is an invalid syntax.  And `Input(batch_shape=(None,))` causes the same error =/

Comment: what is shape of trainInputEncoded?

Comment: (100, 50, 780) .....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218804/discussion-between-adam-l-and-rahul-vishwakarma).

Comment: Because then your input becomes 3D. On passing through embedding, it becomes 4D. But LSTM takes 3D input. So take mean about an axis before passing through LSTM